# Issue with RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView not being supported : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, android, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I am getting an issue with react-native-gesture-handler library. I have upgraded to the latest version "^2.9.0". I am not able to run my build as it crashes on opening the app giving me a summary:- java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Your application is configured to use RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView which is no longer supported.

I have read the documentation for migrating off RNGHEnabledRootView but that too doesn't solve the problem. I have changed MainActivity.java file by editing :

```
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.RNGestureHandlerPackage;
```

But getting issue with :

```
@Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegateWrapper(this, new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
            @Override
            protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
                return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
            }
        });
    }
```

error: cannot find symbol
return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
^
symbol: class RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView

Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According [to this page](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/guides/migrating-off-rnghenabledroot) in the documentation, you have to remove `RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView` and use the below code in your `MainActivity`

Java:

```java
@Override
protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new MainActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName());
}
```

Kotlin:

```kotlin
override fun createReactActivityDelegate(): ReactActivityDelegate? {
    return MainActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName())
}
```